# Quantum computing, NP complexity

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, algorithms

Hi I have a very limited knowledge of quantum physics and its bothering me trying to understand quantum computing.

I want understand how a qubit can return usable data faster then a regular bit, how is the NP complexity not an obstacle?

Comment: I think it could be asked easier, how can a qubits results be interpreted faster then regular bits?

Comment: OK, thanks for helping, I know the question is difficult but I am hoping there is someone who can make an analogy in a simple enough way that it helps everyone understand more about this topic.

Comment: Try asking a more precise question -- it is easier to answer, and people will be less worried spending time on an answer which will leave you dissatisfied.  Did you try to read up on this on the internet?  What did you find, and what did you like/not like about it?

Comment: Your best bet, I think, is to actually work through a quantum computing algorithm by hand to see what happens.  Try using Shor's algorithm to factor the number 15.

Comment: I have read and listened to lectures, I have found that this is the best way to ask the question from my current understanding of superposition, observer effect, probability and the grover algorithm. I cant make the leap that retrieving the probable solution by iteration on a qubit can lead to anything but E as the output given the fact each iteration would change the state of the bit and only another probability, recursive it would seem and thats where my question stands. someone will answer it.

Comment: No doubt somene will answer it. Putting more effort into the question might however help you to get more satisfactory answers -- otherwise you'll just get iterated what you find on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to understand this is to work through an example.  Here is how you factor the number 15 using Shor's algorithm.  (If you prefer, view the problem not as factoring 15 but as solving $2^r=1 \hbox(mod 15)$, and skip Step Seven).  As you work through this, imagine replacing 15 with a much larger composite number, and you'll see the advantage of having the quantum algorithm.

**Step One**.  Prepare a register in
the state
$$|1>+|2>+|3>+|4>+|5>+|6>+|7>+|8>
+|9>+|10>+|11>+|12>+|13>+|14>+|15>$$

**Step Two**.  Apply the function
$x\mapsto 2^x$ (mod 15) to the above
register and put the result in a
second register.  The second register
now contains:
$$|2>+|4>+|8>+|1>+
|2>+|4>+|8>+|1>+
|2>+|4>+|8>+|1>+
|2>+|4>+|8>+|1>$$
which is the same as
$$|2>+|4>+|8>+|1>$$

**Step Three.** Observe the second
register.  With equal probabilities,
we might observe $2$, $4$, $8$, or
$1$.  For illustration, let's suppose
we observe $2$.  (The other cases are
similar.)

**Step Four.**  Now the first register
contains
$$1>+|5>+|9>+|13>$$
These differ by 4, but we don't know
this because we haven't done the
computations necessary to carry this
out (actually we {\it have/} done
them in this example with $N=15$, but
they'd be prohibitively costly if $N$
were huge.)  If we knew that the
difference was 4, we could skip to
Step 7.  As it is, let's call the
difference $r$ because it's still
unknown to us.

**Step Five.**  Apply the function
$$x\mapsto \sum_ye^{2\pi i x
y/15}|y>$$
to the first register and put the
result in the second register.
The second register now contains
$$\sum_y \Big(e^{2\pi i  y/15}
          +e^{2\pi i 5 y/15}
          +e^{2\pi i 9 y/15}
          +e^{2\pi i 15 y /15}\Big)|y>$$

Numerically, the norms of the
coefficients are given approximately
by the following table:
$$\matrix{
|y>&\hbox{ Norm of Coefficient}\cr
1&.9\cr
2&1.7\cr
3&2.6\cr
4&2.5\cr
5&1\cr
6&.4\cr
7&2\cr
8&2\cr
9&.4\cr
10&1\cr
11&2.5\cr
12&2.6\cr
13&1.7\cr
14&.9\cr
15&4\cr}$$
which peaks (this is no accident) near
$y=3,4,7,8,11,12,15$---the values
where $4y/15$ is close to an integer.

**Step Six.**  Observe the second
register.  If you get $y=15$, you
learn
nothing.  Otherwise, you probably get
$y=3,4,7,8,11$ or $12$---which allows
you to
guess---after a couple of trials---
that $r=4$, based on the knowledge
that $yr/15$ is probably close to an
integer.

**Step Seven.**  Now we know that $r=4$,
which tells us that $2^4=1$ (mod
$15$).  So 15 divides $2^4-1=(2^2-
1)(2^2+1)=3\times 5$.  Choose either
factor (say 3) and compute its
greatest common divisor with 15 using
euclid's algorithm.  This gives 3.
Therefore 3 is a factor of 15.

Comment: Thanks for an answer with great detail, It certainly helps to visualize the process, I will have a read on the algorithm you mentioned, thanks for walking through the steps.

Comment: I thought it was not known if factorization is actually NP-hard? We certainly don't have a classical polynomial algorithm for it, but we don't seem to have a proof, either, that none can exist.

Comment: @CuriousOne:  It is indeed not known whether factorization is NP-hard.  But I understood the question to ask how it is possible for a quantum algorithm to overcome the problem of NP-hardness.  The Shor algorithm demonstrates that by factoring numbers quickly *whether or not* the factorization problem is NP-hard.

Comment: @WillO: Just for my own curiosity, is there a quantum algorithm that moves a problem that would be at least exponential into the polynomial domain? It's obvious that NP also contains super-exponential problems... but do we have an explicit example of an exponential problem, even if we may not have the actual quantum algorithm, yet? Your answer is great, by the way, it helped me to understand the details a little better. I apologize for asking a question in a comment.

Comment: @CuriousOne:  This doesn't answer your question, but answers a different question that's close in spirit:  Grover's quantum search algorithm reduces a problem that is known to be $O(N)$ classically to a problem that is $O(N^{1/2})$.   As to the exact question you asked, there might be a very well known answer, but I do not know it.

Comment: @CuriousOne NP does not contain super-exponential problems, it does not even contain all problems which can be solved in exponential time.  It only contains those problems where a poly-sized solution can be verified in polynomial time. (It is easy to see that this allows you to solve it in exponential time by brute-force checking all solutions.) -- As to quantum computing, it is widely believed that quantum computer *cannot* solve all problems in NP (and in particular no NP-hard problems).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: You are correct, that was misnomer. As to beliefs... I don't even believe that quantum computers are significantly better than classical computers, even though it is clear that the opposite (and in my opinion naive) religious belief is out there.

Comment: @CuriousOne You don't believe that they will be significantly better in practice, or not even on paper?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: What's the difference if your theory is correct? The claims of quantum computing stand and fall with the validity of measurement being represented by operators. That is a naive approximation of a real measurement. I have a gut feeling that once the measurement is analyzed in terms of a finite readout system the entire quantum computing field will collapse (it may still lead to better "semi-classical computers", though).

Comment: @CuriousOne So basically you say there is a *fundamental* flaw in the axioms of QM. -- But what I meant was: As of now, Shor's algorithms allows us - in theory - to factor in poly time which much better than what we know classically.  Do you believe that these type of separations will break down, or do you just think quantum computing (as we understand it today) cannot be realized experimentally?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: No, the axioms of quantum mechanics are correct in the same sense as the axioms of thermodynamics are correct, in the limit of infinite reservoirs/measurement devices. A practical quantum computer is finite, which means that the correlations in the measurement device will induce a measurement error. What is not clear to me is whether the limit for an ideal classical computer that uses all degrees of freedom in its matter is significantly different from that of a quantum computer. What may be, though, is that QC is a "magical" way of using all of those degrees of freedom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35047/discussion-between-curiousone-and-norbert-schuch).